# DropDownList not modifying binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `DropDownListFor` which is bound to a field in my model called `BinRangeSelection`. When I select a value in this drop downlist, the BinRangeSelection value does not change, it remains null. Here is my drop down:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BinRangeSelection, new SelectList(Model.BinRanges), "Select BIN Range", new { id = "BinRangesDropDown_start", @class = "five columns" })
```

And my `BinRangeSelection` String:

```
private String _BinRangeSelection;

    public String BinRangeSelection
    {
        get
        {
            return _BinRangeSelection;
        }

        set
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("testing");
            string[] rangeSplit = Regex.Split(value, " - ");
            foreach (IdentifiBINConfiguration ibc in IdentifiBINConfigs)
            {
                if (ibc.LowerRange == rangeSplit[0] && ibc.UpperRange == rangeSplit[1])
                {
                    IdentifiBINConfiguration = ibc;
                }
            }

            _BinRangeSelection = value;
            BinRangeSelection = value;
        }
    }
```

That `testing` statement is never printing to the console, and I've placed break points and nothing in the set function is being called.

Comment: you have an infinite loop by setting `BinRangeSelection` inside of `set`

Comment: @DLeh How do I set it without calling an infinite loop?

Comment: you're setting both `_BinRangeSelection` and `BinRangeSelection`, you only need to set the first one. The second one will re-call the same setter.

Comment: when are you expecting it to fire the setter? It won't fire until you submit the form. It won't fire just when you select a dropdown option.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thanks! Edit: It won't fire until I submit the form? Ok, that helps a lot actually. I figured it would be called whenever a value was selected.